# How to import a global variable from one folder into another folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I tried to find the answer to my question before writing here, but I could not. My question is how to import a global variable from one folder into another folder without initializing a class.

For an example

```
#folder1
#example1.py
class Example1(object):
    def __init__(self,var1, var2,var3): 
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def train_step():
        global tag
        tag = '1234'
```

Second folder

```
#folder2
#example2.py

from ..folder1.example1 import Example1 
#here i need to use tag variable without initializing the Example1 class.
```

I know without instantiation, we can not use any class variable and functions, since variable is global. So, I just need to know, is there any way to use it?. which I do not know.

To instantiate, I need to provide lots of variables in my case. that is the reason, I am trying to use global variable with just import the file from another folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way, because the `global tag` is  defined inside the body of the function and that line is not executed if you don't call that function.

On the other hand, the body of the class "is" executed while creating the class itself. so why not just define `tag` as a class variable ? Then you can access it through classname, without getting instance from it.

In example1.py:

```
class Example:
    tag = '1234
```

In example2.py:

```
from ..folder1.example1 import Example1
print(Example1.tag)
```

Comment: my class need lots of variables to instantiate. So I make the variable as global.

Comment: @mariya Then why don't you specify them outside the class in global ? maybe I don't get what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

> I know without instantiation, we can not use any class variable...

No. We can indeed access class variables without initializing the class.

[Class methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) can be used when you donot need to create instances of the class to access its attributes. Use the `@classmethod` decorator to make a class  method.

```py
#folder1
#example1.py
class Example1(object):
    def __init__(self,var1, var2,var3): 
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    @classmethod
    def train_step(cls):
        tag = '1234'
        return tag
```

```py
#folder2
#example2.py

from folder1.example1 import Example1
TAG = Example1.train_step()
```

Here, in `example2`, you donot need to create an instance the class `Example1` to access `tag` attribute.

Similar results can be obtained by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585528/12982627) also. But the advantage of using class methods is that you can give different tags to different methods without having to create a separate global variable for each of them.

Example :

```py
class Example1:
    @classmethod
    def train_step(cls):
        tag = '1234'
        return tag
    
    @classmethod
    def train_step2(cls):
        tag = "9876"
        return tag
        
print(Example1.train_step()) # prints 1234
print(Example1.train_step2()) # prints 9876
```

Additionally, you can pass in an optional parameter so that the method `train_step` can be used for other stuffs also rather than just returning the `tag`.

Somewhat like :

```py
 class Example1:
    @classmethod
    def train_step(cls, get_tag=False): # get_tag set as False by default 
        tag = "1234"
        if get_tag:
            return tag
        else:
            # Do stuff

print(Example1.train_step(get_tag=True)) # prints 1234
```